# Running a collection in a Newman

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, newman, postman-pre-request-script

I created a collection in *Postman* which contains a single request, I am running the collection by uploading a test case `(.csv)` file, It's working perfectly.

But I want to do the same via *Newman*. So I have installed the *Newman* and I have copied my collection link from the *Postman*, and but I don't know how to pass the test case file to it?

I tried this:

```
newman run https://www.getpostman.com/collections/944624fbc40ec677902e -d /path/to/file
```

but it's not working.

Comment: What is not working? Are you getting an error message? Does the .csv file contain data that's being referenced in the request using variables?

Comment: I am doing like this, newman run https://www.getpostman.com/collections/17207adeede6b5fa523b -d //Desktop//SAFE_TESTCASE_AUTOMATION//CC_API_INPUT_TESTCASES//safe.csv, for this I am getting newman: Newman v4 deprecates support for the v1 collection format
  Use the Postman Native app to export collections in the v2 format

error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, open '\\Desktop\SAFE_TESTCASE_AUTOMATION\CC_API_INPUT_TESTCASES\safe.csv' error, I tried with single backslash also then also it saying unable to acces file

Comment: for this newman run https://www.getpostman.com/collections/17207adeede6b5fa523b -d /Users/harish.shet/Desktop/SAFE_TESTCASE_AUTOMATION/CC_API_INPUT_TESTCASES/safe.csv 
error: Invalid opening quote at line 3

Comment: What is `data` in the `var newData = data` line? To assess the in the csv file from the Pre-request Script, you should use `pm.iterationData.get('your_csv_column_header')`

Comment: here data refers to the entire row in the csv, I am copying that to a another variable, as my api body requires keys: value=>(value should be in quotes,), here you find the sample row, METHOD,url,subscriber,action,numberType,sender,expected_response

Comment: Seemingly you are using Windows, so could you try to pass Full Path to your .csv file instead of relative path?

Comment: Also, I would try to import collection and try to run Newman using collection on the local machine (without .csv file at first). If doesn't work as well, then most probably path issue.